# Woocommerce YITH Product Filter not working

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, filtering, product

In WooCommerce have been able to successfully make out of stock products to be displayed only on product category archives pages (so not in shop archive pages) with [this answer code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47858352/hide-out-of-stock-products-only-on-shop-archive-pages-in-woocommerce/47859012#47859012):

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_query_meta_query', 'shop_only_instock_products', 10, 2 );
function shop_only_instock_products( $meta_query, $query ) {
    // Only on shop archive pages
    if( is_admin() || is_search() || ! is_shop() ) return $meta_query;

    $meta_query[] = array(
        'key'     => '_stock_status',
        'value'   => 'outofstock',
        'compare' => '!='
    );
    return $meta_query;
}
```

But I am using [YITH WooCommerce Ajax Product Filter](https://wordpress.org/plugins/yith-woocommerce-ajax-navigation/) plugin, enabled and working on my shop pages.

The problem that I have now is when I want to filter out of stock products on product category archives pages, I get no filtered results and all products disappear.

I have tried to change the priority of the hook decreasing it first and then increasing it too, without any success.

I have tried adding the following filter:

```
add_filter ('yith_wcan_use_wp_the_query_object', '__return_true');
```

But it's not working either.

How can I solve this issue? Any help on this will be appreciated

Comment: Unfortunately, this didn't work. :/

Comment: This was the first step to try… I haven't used this YITH plugin yet, so the right way should be to look in the plugin source code, to find out some way to get this working. Or may be to find out something that will prevent this issue. But it's not so simple... You could also try to ask in their support pages adding a link to this thread...

Comment: I've posted last night a topic on Wordpress.org support for YITH, but no answer. The topics in general are kind of dead, a lot of them has no answers.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking around and figure out that the problem is in the thing that YITH Product Filter, when used on category page, redirects to a shop page and since the shop page has out-of-stock products excluded, it shows no results.

URL structure of Shop page without the filter:

```
domain.com/shop
```

URL structure of Shop page with applied filter:

```
domain.com/shop?filter_watch-gender=gender-men&query_type_watch-gender=or
```

URL structure of the category page that shows out-of-stock products, without applied filter:

```
domain.com/product-category/our-collection/
```

URL structure of the category page with applied filter, the same one that was applied on the Shop page:

```
domain.com/shop?product_cat=our-collection&source_id=25&source_tax=product_cat&filter_watch-gender=gender-men&query_type_watch-gender=or
```

URL structure that should be once the filter is applied on the category page:

```
domain.com/product-category/our-collection?filter_watch-gender=gender-men&query_type_watch-gender=or
```

I've tested this last URL structure on the category page with out-of-stock products, and it showed me the desired results, it has narrowed the list of products based on the applied filter.

I don't know if this can be useful to someone who might know how to help me :)

Comment: Does anyone have any idea? I tried everything I know and nothing works. I really need this to get fixed.