# Hide "out of stock" products on home page in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, hook-woocommerce

I don't want to display "out of stock" products on my home page.
I have tried some WooCommerce hooks and filter to alter product query but its not working.
I have also checked "hide out of stock" into woocommerce setting area.

but product are still appearing. Can I get the clue, wh its happening.

I tried this filter hook to alter main product query:

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'custom_pre_get_posts_query' );

function custom_pre_get_posts_query( $q ) {

if ( ! $q->is_main_query() ) return;
if ( ! $q->is_post_type_archive() ) return;
if ( ! is_admin() ) {


$q->set( 'meta_query', array(array(
    'key'       => '_stock_status',
    'value'     => 'outofstock',
    'compare'   => 'NOT IN'
)));

}

remove_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'custom_pre_get_posts_query' );

}
```

I want to hide out of stock products but nothing is working. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

To exclude "Out of stock" products from your homepage, it can be done in different ways.

1) **A Meta Query** using dedicated `woocommerce_product_query_meta_query` filter hook:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_query_meta_query', 'filter_product_query_meta_query', 10, 2 );
function filter_product_query_meta_query( $meta_query, $query ) {
    // On woocommerce home page only
    if( is_front_page() ){
        // Exclude products "out of stock"
        $meta_query[] = array(
            'key'     => '_stock_status',
            'value'   => 'outofstock',
            'compare' => '!=',
        );
    }
    return $meta_query;
}
```

2) **A Tax Query** using dedicated `woocommerce_product_query_tax_query` filter hook:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_query_tax_query', 'filter_product_query_tax_query', 10, 2 );
function filter_product_query_tax_query( $tax_query, $query ) {
    // On woocommerce home page only
    if( is_front_page() ){
        // Exclude products "out of stock"
        $tax_query[] = array(
            'taxonomy' => 'product_visibility',
            'field'    => 'name',
            'terms'    => array('outofstock'),
            'operator' => 'NOT IN'
        );
    }
    return $tax_query;
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Both works.

---

Related: [Hide out of stock products only on shop archive pages in Woocommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47858352/hide-out-of-stock-products-only-on-shop-archive-pages-in-woocommerce/47859012#47859012)

Comment: It also perfectly works on "Visual composer" Woocommerce widgets.

Answer (score 1):

You are using code for old WooCommerce version. Try this approach.

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'custom_pre_get_posts_query' );

function custom_pre_get_posts_query( $q ) {

    if ( ! $q->is_main_query() || is_admin() || ! $q->is_front_page() ) {
        return;
    }

    if ( $outofstock_term = get_term_by( 'name', 'outofstock', 'product_visibility' ) ) {

        $tax_query = (array) $q->get('tax_query');

        $tax_query[] = array(
            'taxonomy' => 'product_visibility',
            'field' => 'term_taxonomy_id',
            'terms' => array( $outofstock_term->term_taxonomy_id ),
            'operator' => 'NOT IN'
        );

        $q->set( 'tax_query', $tax_query );

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**

Check `font-page.php` file in your current theme folder, maybe your developers have added a custom code into your template files without calling any hook actions.

**OLD ANSWER**

Why don't use WooCommerce Settings?

1. Go to Woocommerce → Settings and click the Products tab
2. Click the Inventory link at the top
3. Check the **Hide out of stock items from the catalog** option to hide out of stock items

Comment: Because it's only for home page (as title says) and if you read the question, the OP as already tried what you are suggesting.